# Почему VS требует установки уже установленной версии .NET Framework

Tags: .net, visual-studio

**Описание проблемы**

Всё работало до момента когда я изменил версию .NET Framework на 4.7.2. После этого появилась такая ошибка при запуске:

```
This application requires one of the following versions of the .NET Framework:

.NET Framework, version=4.7.2

Do you want to install this .NET Framework version now?
```

[image: Ошибка]

Я подумал - фиг с ним, установил. Но нет, ничего не изменилось, всё ещё требуется установка. "Восстановил" в установщике, перезагрузил компьютер - ничего не помогло. Ошибка всё ещё тут. Нужная версия .NET Framework в списке программ есть.

[image: Список установленных программ - всё что нужно вроде установленно]

Comment: Вам нужен пакет разработчика SDK, а у вас только targeting pack как я вижу. Можно скачать отсюда Developer Pack: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks Но вроде лучше выбрать нужные пакеты из установщика Visual Studio.

Comment: @AlexKrass натыкал все возможные пункты установки .NET в Visual Studio Installer, установил - SDK, Targeting Pack ещё раз переустановил - оно в списке программ не появилось. Перезапустил компьютер - не появилось. И что самое главное, ошибка всё ещё здесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы не называл это решением проблемы. Я бы не называл бы даже это правильным выбором, потому что это именно уклонение от решения проблемы.

**Тем не менее мои проблемы решила смена на более новую версию .NET Framework, а конкретно на уже установленную 4.8**. Если кому-то интересно, как я "додумался" до этого, то меня на это натолкнуло вот это из оф. документации Microsoft (статья: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/troubleshoot-blocked-installations-and-uninstallations)

> Because the 4.x versions of the .NET Framework are in-place updates, you cannot install an earlier version of the .NET Framework 4.x on a system that already has a later version installed.